# SQL: large case conditions GROUP BY clause slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract a report base on LC call number base on the number range. The call number format will be as below pattern and I need to extract the 2nd field before the punctuation for grouping:

```
CALL_NO_ID1
--------------
a!3243 .m43 12

a#435 234 1999

cs"345 1973.

...
```

Follow is my sql

```
select count("CALL_NO_ID1") "No_of_Items", 
case

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 0 AND 999)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'KG %') THEN 'KG 0-999  - Federal law Common and collective state law Individual states US - Latin AmericaGeneral'

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 0 AND 999)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'KH %') THEN 'KH 0-999 - Federal law Common and collective state law Individual states US -  South AmericaGeneral '

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 1 AND 100)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'DE %') THEN 'DE 1-100  - HistoryGeneral - The Mediterranean Region The Greco-Roman World'

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 1 AND 1050)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'TR %') THEN 'TR 1-1050  - Photography'

...  

... (around 450 case conditions)

...

else "CALL_NO_ID1"

end "Primary Call"

from DWH_FACT_ITEMS

group by 

case

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 0 AND 999)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'KG %') THEN 'KG 0-999  - Federal law Common and collective state law Individual states US - Latin AmericaGeneral'

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 0 AND 999)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'KH %') THEN 'KH 0-999 - Federal law Common and collective state law Individual states US -  South AmericaGeneral '

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 1 AND 100)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'DE %') THEN 'DE 1-100  - HistoryGeneral - The Mediterranean Region The Greco-Roman World'

WHEN (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 1 AND 1050)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'TR %') THEN 'TR 1-1050  - Photography'
...  
... (around 450 case conditions)
...
```

However it will take very long time to get the result(2~3hrs), I would like to know any suggestion to improve my sql?

Thanks!

Moris

Comment: Can you clue us in in the logic used in your `CASE` statements and the grouping process?

Comment: you need a algorithm to cut those case when out

Comment: The grouping is base on the LC Classification and the 1st or "1st and 2nd" must be English character.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
It is LC Classification, the 1st or "1st and 2nd" must be English character.
Then follow by a number with field separator "white space", ! , # or " 

a!3243 .m43 12 (record in db)
--> a (1st field)
--> 3243 (2nd field)
--> .m43 (3rd field)
a#435 234 1999 (record in db)
--> a (1st field)
--> 234 (2nd field)
--> 1999 (3rd field)
cs"345 1973. (record in db)
--> cs (1st field)
--> 345 (2nd field)
--> 1973. (3rd field)

Comment: As the requirement is to extract the total of record in range according to the given 1st and 2nd fields for the grouping, e.g.
field 1(start with a) and field 2 range (1-400) is A group
field 1(start with a) and field 2 range (500-4000) is B group
field 1(start with b) and field 2 range (1-400) is C group
....

I think above case conditions is irregular.

Comment: What is the number of the rows in the table?

Comment: There are over 400k records in the table and the sql in query is 905 line

Answer (score 0):

I would add an additional column `CALL_NO_CLEARED` to keep the number. Apply your expression to all values to fill the artificial column.

You can add a trigger `ON INSERT/UPDATE` to fill the column on fly when it's added or changed.

Then you can use the `CALL_NO_CLEARED` in your select introducing index to make it faster.

UPDATE:

I could suggest another way. It seems that most time consuming process is the call

```
LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0')
```

So for each row we calculate it 450 times (for each of the `WHEN` mentioned)

Try to place the calculation in a subquery and then apply the group by later e.g.

```
select *
FROM (
    select 
    CALL_NO_ID1,
    LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') as sub_num
    from DWH_FACT_ITEMS) sub
group by 
case
WHEN (sub.sub_num BETWEEN 0 AND 999)AND (sub.CALL_NO_DESC1 LIKE 'KG %') THEN 'KG 0-999  - Federal law Common and collective state law Individual states US - Latin AmericaGeneral'
...
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and it should be get the result very if apply your suggestion. But the db is maintained by vendor. Modify the table may violate the contract and it may cause a problem for the future upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and I tried to revise the sql as your suggest. The execute time is no difference.

Comment: Hi StanislavL,

Even I change the order or case, I can feel the significant improvement.

Many thanks,

Moris

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities to improve the query. My tests show, that the
elimination of the case in group by (using subquery) improve the maintainability and size of the query, but leave the performance the same.

Particular improvement was observed, by **sorting the case statement so, that the most frequent conditions are placed on the top**.

The idea is simple, if the match is done early in the CASE, the rest of the conditions is skipped.

An even better improvement was achieved  be **reordering the predicates in the WHEN statement**. This will not call the regexp processing if the CALL_NO_DESC sub-string doesn't match.

```
WHEN ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'TR %') and 
(LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') BETWEEN 1 AND 1050)   
THEN 'TR 1-4050  - Photography'
```

Final step was to **call the REGEXP processing only once in a subquery**.

Putting it all together, I end with this query reducing the elapsed time dramatically (with my test data).

```
with dta as (
select "CALL_NO_ID1",
LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') parsed_num,
"CALL_NO_DESC1"
from DWH_FACT_ITEMS
),
dta2 as (
select 
CALL_NO_ID1, CALL_NO_DESC1,
case
-- put the most frequent condition on the top
-- start with the most selective predicate
WHEN ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'TR %') and parsed_num BETWEEN 1 AND 1050  THEN 'TR 1-4050  - Photography'
--....
else "CALL_NO_ID1"
end "Primary Call"
from dta
)
select count("CALL_NO_ID1") "No_of_Items","Primary Call"
from dta2
group by "Primary Call"
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WITH` clause and `/*+ MATERIALIZE */` hint to have Oracle do each expensive operation only once.

This should perform much better than 2-3 hours on 400,000 rows:

```
WITH parsed_call_numbers as ( SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */
SELECT CALL_NO_ID1,
       (LPAD(CAST(regexp_replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE("CALL_NO_ID1",'["]|[#]|[!]', ' '),'[^ ]+|["]|[#]',1,2), '[^0-9]+', '') as number),7,'0') call_Number_part,
       CALL_NO_DESC1
from DWH_FACT_ITEMS ) ,
primary_calls AS ( SELECT /*+ MATERIALIZE */ 
CALL_NO_ID1,
case
WHEN call_number_part BETWEEN 0 AND 999)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'KG %') THEN 'KG 0-999  - Federal law Common and collective state law Individual states US - Latin AmericaGeneral'
WHEN call_number_part BETWEEN 0 AND 999)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'KH %') THEN 'KH 0-999 - Federal law Common and collective state law Individual states US -  South AmericaGeneral '
WHEN call_number_part BETWEEN 1 AND 100)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'DE %') THEN 'DE 1-100  - HistoryGeneral - The Mediterranean Region The Greco-Roman World'
WHEN call_number_part BETWEEN 1 AND 1050)AND ("CALL_NO_DESC1" LIKE 'TR %') THEN 'TR 1-1050  - Photography'
--...  
--... (around 450 case conditions)
--...
else "CALL_NO_ID1"
end "Primary Call"
from parsed_call_numbers )
select count("CALL_NO_ID1") "No_of_Items", "Primary Call"
FROM primary_calls
group by "Primary Call"
```